# Is there an add-on to view the CURRENT source of an HTML page after AJAX components have been triggered?

Tags: html, firefox, firefox-addon, generated-code

In Firefox (Windows) when you view source from the browser it will not update the source on a page if certain AJAX components have changed. An example is you navigate to the page and it fully loads.

An AJAX component triggers and changes the source, but if you click view source after this event it will not register. If you download the HTML file and then view in an external program it will show the change.

Is there anyway to quickly view the current source accurately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) can do this.

Answer (score 3):

The web developer toolbar does this too.

Once installed, in the "View Source" sub-menu, there's an option for "View Generated Source"

Answer (score 1):

ctrl-A -> rightclick -> View Selection Source